# How to filter data in a dictionary when the values are lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the data structure below and I'd to filter this data using only Python.

```
bd = {
     'portfolio': ['long_term', 'medium_term', 'short_term', 'long_term', 'short_term'], 
     'asset_type':['stock', 'etf', 'bonds', 'bonds', 'stock'],
     'value':[2000, 3000, 5000, 8000, 1000]
}
```

My goal is to have the following result:

```
long_term_list = 10000 # (2000 + 8000)

stock_list = 3000 # (2000 + 1000)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you also demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that is by including the text based version of the code you have so far (even if it does not work). Per @martineau I really should not have answer this question as is. If you want a nudge getting started, check out `zip()` and `setdefault()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
bd = {
     'portfolio': ['long_term', 'medium_term', 'short_term', 'long_term', 'short_term'], 
     'asset_type':['stock', 'etf', 'bonds', 'bonds', 'stock'],
     'value':[2000, 3000, 5000, 8000, 1000]
}

long_term_list = sum([bd['value'][i] for i, x in enumerate(bd['portfolio']) if x == "long_term"])

stock_list = sum([bd['value'][i] for i, x in enumerate(bd['asset_type']) if x == "stock"])

print(long_term_list, stock_list)
```

Gives output

```
10000 3000
```